# Replace duplicates with NAs within a row across columns

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data frame in R that looks like this:

```
ID sex height coordinate.1 coordinate.2 coordinate.3 coordinate.4
12 m 1.81 1223 NA NA 1223
13 f 1.65 5664 4667 NA 4667
15 m 1.78 6663 NA 6663 NA
```

For each row, I want to only keep the unique variables among the four coordinate.*x* variables, and the duplicates should be replaced with NAs. The result should look like this:

```
ID sex height coordinate.1 coordinate.2 coordinate.3 coordinate.4
12 m 1.81 1223 NA NA NA
13 f 1.65 5664 4667 NA NA
15 m 1.78 6663 NA NA NA
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply` for every row we `replace` the values which are `duplicated` with `NA`.

```
cols <- grep("^coordinate", names(df))
df[cols] <- t(apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)))

df
#  ID sex height coordinate.1 coordinate.2 coordinate.3 coordinate.4
#1 12   m   1.81         1223           NA           NA           NA
#2 13   f   1.65         5664         4667           NA           NA
#3 15   m   1.78         6663           NA           NA           NA
```

---

A `tidyverse` approach would be by creating a `row_number()` for every row, `gather` all `coordinate...` values `group_by` the row number (`ind`), `replace` duplicates with `NA` and `spread` the values again in wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, -(c(ind, ID:height))) %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  mutate(value = replace(value, duplicated(value), NA)) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-ind)


#       ID sex   height coordinate.1 coordinate.2 coordinate.3 coordinate.4
#     <int> <fct>  <dbl>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
#1       12 m       1.81         1223           NA           NA           NA
#2       13 f       1.65         5664         4667           NA           NA
#3       15 m       1.78         6663           NA           NA           NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea for fun avoiding the `apply(..., margin = 1, ..)`

```
library(tidyverse)

stack(df[-c(1:3)]) %>% 
 mutate(values = replace(values, duplicated(values), NA)) %>% 
 unstack() %>% 
 bind_cols(df[c(1:3)], .)
```

which gives,

> ```
>   ID sex height coordinate.1 coordinate.2 coordinate.3 coordinate.4
> 1 12   m   1.81         1223           NA           NA           NA
> 2 13   f   1.65         5664         4667           NA           NA
> 3 15   m   1.78         6663           NA           NA           NA
> ```